# passing 2 arguments for @selector in its simplest way

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
SEL twoArgumentSelector = @selector(methodWithTwoArguments:and:); 

[newsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(twoArgumentSelector) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)methodWIthTwoArguments:(id)argumentOne and:(id)argumentTwo;
```

I have seen some examples that let you use two arguments in a selector. How would any do that in the above code? ty in advance.

Comment: I don't think it would work the way you want it to here - unless you have newsButton subclassed and you are customizing the action sequence.

Comment: I just wonder what the and:(id)argumentTwo passes and return.  it looks like argumentOne and argumentTwo the same to me.  So i want to know what's the difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@selector(twoArgumentSelector:and:)
```

although I'm not sure how you would send two arguments with a control event...

edit:

you know that the selector isn't actually calling the method, so you can't pass the arguments with the selector. It is basically just the name for a block of code (the method). Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html). A better solution would be to have the control event call a separate method which could then determine the arguments to send to the method with 2 parameters.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the OP has in the question?  `@selector(methodWithTwoArguments:and:)`

Comment: Yeah, I'm equally confused now, since the OP wrote `@selector(twoArgumentSelector)` which is... well, wrong.

Comment: the way I wrote it is how you would make the method a selector. Although it wouldn't even work in this case because the method is expecting a selector that only takes one argument

Answer (score 1):

UIControls events by will only send a reference to themselves if their target selector allows for one argument. This is all you get. UIButton is one such UIControl subclass.

```
- (void)buttonAction:(id)sender; //(reference to button)
```

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to make another method on your button target (in this case `self`) that calls out to your two argument selector.

```
[newsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:...];

- (void)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
  [self methodwithTwoArguements:sender and:otherObject];
}
```

This could also be solved with a UIButton subclass, but depending on what your second argument needs to be, this is the *simplest* way.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are subclassing the object, there is no need for this because the argument to UIControlEvents is the id of the instance sending the event. You can get all the information you could possibly need from that instance.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [NSInvocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsinvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Here's an example:

```
SEL mySelector; // 2 parameter selector.

// ...

NSMethodSignature *signature = [[MyClass class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:mySelector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[invocation setTarget:myTarget];
[invocation setArgument:arg1 atIndex:0];
[invocation setArgument:arg2 atIndex:1];
[invocation invoke];
```

This will do exactly what you want.

It's worth noting, however, that the control event you are binding to isn't going to pass anything in for a second parameter. This will only work if, by contract, the object that is calling back actually has a second parameter to pass in.

Comment: `UIControl` doesn't let you set an `NSInvocation` as the response to a control event.

Comment: I know. I mentioned that in my post. UIControl events don't have a necessity to pass two parameters into their event handlers anyways. I just provided an example of how you can write a method that takes targets and selectors and invokes them with > 1 parameter.